# Discontinuity in multivariable calculus

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

Show that the function

F(x, y) = x(1 - cos(x - y))/(x  y)^2

has removable discontinuity along the line x = y. Which values should we
assign to this function on the diagonal x = y in order to turn it into an
everywhere continuous function?

-I know how to show it has a removable discontinuity at x=y. However I do not know how to turn the function into a continuous function

Comment: You probably mean $(x-y)^2$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Define $F(x,x) := \lim_{y \to x} F(x,y)$.